# My prefix is a human being, My infix is an insect being

Tags: riddle, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a human being.
>
> My suffix tells you it is what.
>
> My infix is an insect being.
>
> I have features that can cut.

Comment: Is the inversion in the 2nd line ('it is what' instead of 'what it is') a clue or not ?

Comment: @ThePainfull I believe it is just to make the riddle rhyme

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the rhyme. Seems to make sense

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe this is

> **MANTIS**

---

My prefix is a human being.

> 'MAN'

My suffix tells you it is what.

> 'TIS' is short for 'IT IS'.

My infix is an insect being.

> 'ANT'

I have features that can cut.

> A [mantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis) is an insect renowned for having sharp cutting claws

Comment: I was on the same track, but I didn't thought about rol13('gur nssvkrf bireynccvat')

Comment: Man, 'tis so cool.